# What are the events are fired in the front controller in Magento?

Tags: magento

What are the events are fired in the front controller in Magento and what are the functionality of those events ?

Comment: Trying to pass the oDesk test/certification exam?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for the selfish people like you.

Comment: I don't think I'm wrong here. This sounds like some sort of certification or pre-employment test question, and if so, sourcing answers from the Web *will not do you or those who hire you any favors*. As far as me being selfish, I'd point to the hours I've spent answering hundreds of Magento questions as evidence to the contrary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 4:

- `controller_front_init_before` - the first event triggered and can be used for any sort or redirects, logging or benchmarking
- `controller_front_init_routers` - here custom routers can be added
- `controller_front_send_response_before` - last chance to set cookie, modify output or close benchmark. Note: That's why it is not a good idea to echo anything in action controller.
- `controller_front_send_response_after` - here you can clean or write cache, log something, any other cleaning or action user doesn't have to wait for.